# Cannot create template vector iterator

Tags: c++, templates, generics, stl

I have a template class and I want to add instances of this class in a `vector`, then iterate through that `vector`.

With the following code:

```
template <typename T>
class a { };

template <typename T>
void test(vector< a<T> >) {
    vector< a<T> >::iterator it;
}
```

I get the error:

```
In function ‘void test(std::vector<a<T>, std::allocator<a<T> > >)’:
error: expected `;' before ‘it’
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
typename vector< a<T> >::iterator it;
```

since `iterator` is a dependent name in this context. This means that the compiler cannot know whether `something<template parameter>::iterator` is a type or something else. Explicitly adding the `typeneme` keyword resolves that issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename T>
void test(vector< a<T> >) {
    vector< a<T> >::iterator it;
}
```

iterator is `dependent-name`. use `typename vector<a<T> >::iterator it;`

n3337 14.6/2

> A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is
>   dependent on a template-parameter is assumed not to name a type unless
>   the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified
>   by the keyword typename.